# How use Redemption that it works independent from other installed software containing own Redemption Version?

Tags: com, outlook-redemption, side-by-side, regfreecom

We use Redemption  Version 5.21 initializing with [RedemptionLoader](http://dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm#redemptionloader) and 32Bit Outlook.
This works perfect on most systems.

Problems occur on Systems, where a third Software is installed, which is using a customized Redemption.dll together with some Registry-Entries by the setup.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{2D5E2D34-BED5-4B9F-9793-A31E26E6806E}]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{2D5E2D34-BED5-4B9F-9793-A31E26E6806E}\4.5]
@="Redemption Outlook Library. Version 4.5"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{2D5E2D34-BED5-4B9F-9793-A31E26E6806E}\4.5\0]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{2D5E2D34-BED5-4B9F-9793-A31E26E6806E}\4.5\0\win32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\...FullFilePathToCustom_dll
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{2D5E2D34-BED5-4B9F-9793-A31E26E6806E}\4.5\FLAGS]
@="0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{2D5E2D34-BED5-4B9F-9793-A31E26E6806E}\4.5\HELPDIR]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\...DirectoryPath"
```

When deleting the identified Registry-Keys everything works fine.

With this third-Party software installed  there are Problems accessing 
`attachment.ContentID` from singed E-Mails 
and also with 
`decryptedmail = ((IRDOEncryptedMessage)mail).GetDecryptedMessage();`

Conclusion:

Third party-Software adds something to registry, that disturbs the RedemptionLoader Initialisation Process. RedemptionLoader Initialisation is not so isolated from System as expected. Running our software independent from third-Party-Installation is a requirement.

Questions:

1. How get rid of the fact, that third party Installations of redemption influence stability?
2. Is this possible with the RedemptionLoader-Approach?
3. Can  loading [side by side](http://dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm#regfreecom) be a solution?

Comment: may I can add some comInterfaceProxyStub  in Manifest-File: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41146567 https://stackoverflow.com/a/1058978

Comment: Those registry keys should not make any difference. What is the actual problem accessing the content id? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I get a System.AccessViolationException, Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. But only with E-Mails which contain inline-Images

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko If I delete this registry-Key the error ist gone. With this key i see in procMon process requesting Registry ReqQueryValue  "HKCR\TypeLib\{2D5E2D34-BED5-4B9F-9793-A31E26E6806E}\4.5\0\win32\(Default)" and then creating FileMap to dll in Third-Party software.

Comment: Please send a message to redemption (at)  dimastr (dot) com and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.